# SQL to find activity between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the following script to try and count the number of new comments and new discussions created in a group on our system between the last time you visited the group and now.  I have written the following but cant get it to work:

```
SELECT TOP(6) a.GroupID , a. GroupName, sbuser.sf_NewGroupActivity( a.GroupID ,b.LastVisited) AS NumberUpdates
FROM Groups a
INNER JOIN GroupMembers b ON b .GroupID = a.GroupID
WHERE b. MemberID = 102
GROUP BY a.GroupID , a.GroupName, b.LastVisited
ORDER BY NumberUpdates ASC
```

and the sf script is as follows:

```
RETURNS INT
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @OUTSTR INT
    DECLARE @OUT1 INT
    DECLARE @OUT2 INT
    SET @OUT1 = (SELECT CAST(COUNT(GroupDiscussionsID) AS INT) FROM GroupDiscussions
            WHERE MemberID = @GroupID AND CreateDate BETWEEN @LastVisited AND GetDate())
    SET @OUT2 = (SELECT CAST(COUNT(GroupCommentID) AS INT) FROM GroupComments
            WHERE MemberID = @GroupID AND CreateDate BETWEEN @LastVisited AND GetDate())
    SET @OUTSTR = @OUT1 + @OUT2
    RETURN @OUTSTR
    END
```

I am at a loss as to how to get this to list the top 6 groups that have updates order by number of updates.  Any ideas, suggestions, or solutions would be greatly appreciated.  Many thanks

neojakey

Comment: Did you mean DESC instead of ASC?

Comment: What do you man "can't get it to work"?  What is the problem?

Comment: When I run the script I get all returned as zeros and I know there are updates..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is in the WHERE clause of your function:

```
 WHERE MemberID = @GroupID AND . . .
```

Presumablyl, this should be comparing either MemberIDs or GroupIds, but not to each other.

However, I would strongly suggest that you remove the function call and create a single query for the counts.  This allows the SQL to create a better execution plan.  If you want to do this, and don't know how, post another question.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I overlooked that line of code in the scalar function and I guess I was too tired to spot it..  Many thanks for your assistance.  1 point for you..!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 6 with the *most* updates, rather than *least*, change ASC to DESC:

```
ORDER BY NumberUpdates DESC
```